# query DynamoDB, return result based on timestamp

Tags: python, boto, amazon-dynamodb

Folks,
  I have a DynamoDB table where the HashKey is EmailAddress and RangeKey is a Date...  For example:

```
Hash Key          Range Key
test@test.com     Thu, 03 Oct 2013 14:55:44 GMT
foo@bar.com       Thu, 03 Oct 2013 14:48:12 GMT
```

Now, I would like to query the database to return a list of emails that have been inserted after a certain time :)  Is this possible?  I am starting to think that my Hash Key should be something different, and have another field which stores the Email address itself...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can only do it with a Scan operation, thus eliminating any chance of indexing.

With scan you can add conditions. However as you wrote, this is probably not the best approach to your scenario.